# How do I print jqPlot images?

Tags: jquery, printing, jqplot

I have searched through multiple postings for a solution to printing jqPlot graphs and have not really found a definitive answer.

I have successfully created a `<div>` that is showing 7 different graphs. 
I am using `printElement()` to print the `<div>`, but the graphs are blank. 
I am developing in Chrome but users will be using IE9.

Here is the Javascript:

```
$("#printIt").click(function() {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('B_Vol_graph');
    var canvas = $('#B_Vol_graph').children();
    var dataUrl = canvas[4].toDataURL();
    var img = document.getElementById('B_Vol_Img');
    img.src= dataUrl;
    img.style.display = 'inline-block';
    myDiv.style.display = 'none'
    $("#printReport").printElement();
});
```

There are multiple `<canvas>` elements and I can convert each individually and get part, but not all of the graph. I must be missing something.

What is the proper method for printing this `<div>`?

Comment: please post the code that you have tried. It will allow other to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: I did get this script to print one piece of the plot out. It appears there are 9 <canvas> elements. Each with a part of the graph, but not one overall canvas to convert.

Comment: Sorry! I could not get the script to format better.

Comment: It's ok. I think it would be best to post the code in your question. Simply edit your question and it there.